# How can I add a static method to an existing type?

Tags: typescript

For example, I want to add a static `quote` method to the `RegExp` type:

```
RegExp.quote = (text: String) => { ... };
```

But when I try to do this, I receive the following error:

> The property 'quote' does not exist on value of type '{ $1: string; $2: string; $3: string; $4: string; $5: string; $6: string; $7: string; $8: string; $9: string; lastMatch: string; (pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp; new(pattern: string, flags?: string): RegExp; }'.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid there is only this ugly solution:

```
// add it 
RegExp['quote'] = (whatev:any):any => { return whatev;};

// Use it 
RegExp['quote']('asdf');

// The default behaviour is intact: 
var foo = new RegExp('/asdf/');
```

I thought module would allow it to work but I have verified that it does not.

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824687/390330 
and a feature requets : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/917

Answer (score 1):

See the [issue on Codeplex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1602) - if the issue is accepted you could extend the interface. In the meantime, you could manually make that change to create your own custom lib.d.ts.

```
interface RegExpStatic {
    quote(text: string) : string;
}
```

You can now add and access this property as the type system is aware of it.

Comment: I think this only adds it to *instances* of `RegExp`.

Comment: Ah - yes, they haven't created a backing interface for the static element, they have declared it inline. I have opened an issue - you could temporarily make this change to your `lib.d.ts`: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1602

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** see my other answer. I thought the following would work but it does not

You can extend RegExp using a module:

```
module RegExp{
    export function quote(whatev){return whatev;}
}

RegExp.quote('foo');
```

Basically use a module to add static properties to existing instances.

Comment: I just tried this, but it seemed to overwrite the meaning of `RegExp` so I could no longer instantiate it. I also get a "Duplicate Identifier" error.

Comment: even if does work, it didn't for me beside interface String