# Define prototype function with typescript

Tags: typescript, prototype

When I try to define a prototype function, I get:

> error TS2339: Property 'applyParams' does not exist on type
>   'Function'.

```
Function.prototype.applyParams = (params: any) => {
     this.apply(this, params);
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28020863/1142380

I don't think you need the "`prototype.`" part

Comment: @ToastyMallows but then I get error TS2339: Property 'applyParams' does not exist on type 'FunctionConstructor'. Even with interface FunctionConstructor {
    applyParams(params: any): any;
}

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Define the method on an interface named `Function` in a `.d.ts` file. This will cause it to [declaration merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) with the global `Function` type:

```
interface Function {
    applyParams(params: any): void;
}
```

And you don't want to use an arrow function so that `this` won't be bound to the outside context. Use a regular function expression:

```
Function.prototype.applyParams = function(params: any) {
    this.apply(this, params);
};
```

Now this will work:

```
const myFunction = function () { console.log(arguments); };
myFunction.applyParams([1, 2, 3]);

function myOtherFunction() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
myOtherFunction.applyParams([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: I also tried to use an interface and it still get the error. I tried interface Function and interface FunctionConstructor

Comment: @Alexandre are you using external modules? Define the interface in a definition file (*.d.ts* file) and reference that in your application

Comment: @Alexandre you can see this working [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Function%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20applyParams(params%3A%20any)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AFunction.prototype.applyParams%20%3D%20function%20(params%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this(...params)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20func%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20console.log(arguments)%3B%20%7D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20myOtherFunc()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(arguments)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunc.applyParams(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0D%0AmyOtherFunc.applyParams(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B)

Comment: Thanks for the .d.ts advice

Comment: @DavidSherret "*Define the interface in a definition file (.d.ts file)*", could you elaborate on how to do that?