# Polyfills, Shims & Extensions with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, polyfills

Before I proceed with my question, allow me to point out that I have already done some considerable research into this topic, and have already asked a couple of related questions, which you can find here:

[Extending Object.prototype with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813118/extending-object-prototype-with-typescript)

[Extending instance/static functions on existing prototypes with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816414/extending-instance-static-functions-on-existing-prototypes-with-typescript)

Whilst TypeScript seems to be maturing quite well along it's road to version 1.0, I'd noticed quite early on, in it's infancy that it was not easy to polyfill/shim/monkey patch/extend the functionality of core objects (Object, String, Number, Boolean etc) using TypeScript...however this is perfectly legal in pure JavaScript, and in my opinion, necessary for creating cross browser compatible and compliant APIs.

Now that we are on version 0.9.5 I've noticed much improvement in this area, and we can now extend the prototype of core objects, and it would seem that we can also add static functions to core objects too...HOWEVER...this appears to be buggy!

Consider the following code example:

```
interface Object {
    /********************************/
    /*  Static functions            */
    /********************************/

    // ECMAScript 6 Object.is function
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is
    is(v1: any, v2: any): boolean;

    /********************************/
    /*  Prototype functions         */
    /********************************/

    // Custom method for testing obejct equality (based on Java / C# principles)
    equals(obj: any): boolean;
}

// Object.is polyfill
(() => {
    if(!Object.is) {
        Object.is = function(v1: any, v2: any): boolean {
            if (v1 === 0 && v2 === 0) {
                return 1 / v1 === 1 / v2;
            }
            if (v1 !== v1) {
                return v2 !== v2;
            }
            return v1 === v2;
        }
    }
})();

// Object.prototype.equals implementation
Object.prototype.equals = function(obj: any): boolean {
    return Object.is(obj, this);
}
```

Wanna play with it?...[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Object%20%7B%0A%09/********************************/%0A%09/*%20%20Static%20functions%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*/%0A%09/********************************/%0A%09%0A%09//%20ECMAScript%206%20Object.is%20function%0A%09//%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is%0A%09is%28v1:%20any,%20v2:%20any%29:%20boolean;%0A%09%0A%09/********************************/%0A%09/*%20%20Prototype%20functions%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*/%0A%09/********************************/%0A%09%0A%09//%20Custom%20method%20for%20testing%20obejct%20equality%20%28based%20on%20Java%20/%20C#%20principles%29%0A%09equals%28obj:%20any%29:%20boolean;%0A%7D%0A%0A//%20Object.is%20polyfill%0A%28%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%09if%28!Object.is%29%20%7B%0A%09%09Object.is%20=%20function%28v1:%20any,%20v2:%20any%29:%20boolean%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28v1%20===%200%20&&%20v2%20===%200%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09return%201%20/%20v1%20===%201%20/%20v2;%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09if%20%28v1%20!==%20v1%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09return%20v2%20!==%20v2;%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09return%20v1%20===%20v2;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%29%28%29;%0A%0A//%20Object.prototype.equals%20implementation%0AObject.prototype.equals%20=%20function%28obj:%20any%29:%20boolean%20%7B%0A%09return%20Object.is%28obj,%20this%29;%0A%7D)

You've probably already noticed what's wrong here...interfaces shouldn't contain definitions for static functions, only those which should be bound to the prototype. In this respect, if you check out [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/c9/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts), you will see that static functions are declared differently:

```
declare var Object: {
    new (value?: any): Object;
    (): any;
    (value: any): any;
    prototype: Object;
    getPrototypeOf(o: any): any;
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o: any, p: string): PropertyDescriptor;
    getOwnPropertyNames(o: any): string[];
    create(o: any, properties?: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
    defineProperty(o: any, p: string, attributes: PropertyDescriptor): any;
    defineProperties(o: any, properties: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
    seal(o: any): any;
    freeze(o: any): any;
    preventExtensions(o: any): any;
    isSealed(o: any): bool;
    isFrozen(o: any): bool;
    isExtensible(o: any): bool;
    keys(o: any): string[];
}
```

So that means that we should really be adding `is(v1: any, v2: any): boolean;` to the declaration...but declarations in TypeScript are not open-ended as are interfaces, therefore this is not possible.

That being said, if I remove the declaration from the interface, TypeScript then complains that `Object.is` does not exist...so it would appear that I HAVE TO have it in there for the polyfill to work!

"Well if it works...kinda what's the problem?" - Yes it works, but only just and it's not elegant by any means.

Because is has been implemented statically, yet it is contracted as part of Object, TypeScript intellisense is still expecting `Object.prototype.is` AND does not recognize the existence of `Object.is`

I feel like I'm waffling now so I'll get to the point.

1. Is this a known issue?
2. have I missed something?
3. What is in the pipeline to rectify this issue?

**NOTE:** I've just noticed, it appears that you can overwrite declarations now, so you could add `is(v1: any, v2: any): boolean;` to the declaration by overwriting it completely...but I still feel that this is not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concern has been raised. The main reasons for not naming the type of the `Object` var were that we wanted to avoid making a name at all (what would you call it?), and that it would make it more difficult in the future to transition this type into a class shape without causing a breaking change.

The best solution on your end is to have a custom lib.d.ts for your project; as long as the compiler can find some types with the names of the primitive types (Number, String, etc) it doesn't actually matter what the content of lib.d.ts is. So you could either have e.g. lib-es6.d.ts that added the new members directly to those anonymous types, or have e.g. lib-extensible.d.ts that changed the anonymous types into named interfaces so you could extend them in a polyfill definition file elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I fully understand your argument, though it's clear that you are highly knowledgeable regarding TypeScript design. I'm not sure why you would want to transition things like Object, String, Number etc. into classes in future, as classes in TypeScript generate an implementation, whereas these objects are provided natively by the runtime. Therefore it seems more fitting to just declare their implementation to the compiler in TypeScript (if that makes sense). My point is that the declaration "should/could" be open ended as with interfaces, thus static members could be added too.